# ContextWrapper and AssetManager Errors in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dependencies

I am trying to create an Android app in Android Studio, using Java that will import data from a CSV file to the SQLite database. The problem is that when I am trying to read from the CSV file using the code:

1st attempt:

```java
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class LocalFileParser extends ActivityHome {
  final static Path PATH = Paths.get("src\\main\\res\\raw\\recipescsv.csv");
  File file = new File(String.valueOf(PATH));
  BufferedReader buffer;
  String line ="";
  String [] str;

    public LocalFileParser() throws IOException {
          try {
              InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.recipescsv);
              BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
              reader.readLine();
              while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  str = line.trim().split(",");
              }
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          parseToDb();
    }

  private void parseToDb() {
      for(int i=0; i< str.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("This is the array of file: "+str[i]); //For testing

        Database db = new Database(getApplicationContext());
        int id = Integer.parseInt(str[0]), execTime = Integer.parseInt(str[9]), difRate= Integer.parseInt(str[10]);
        double calories = Double.parseDouble(str[6]);
        db.writeJSONtoTheDB(id,str[1],str[2],str[3],str[4],str[5],calories,str[7],null,execTime,difRate);
      }
    }
}
```

The error for this attempt is the following (in ContextWrapper.java):

[image: ContextWrapper import Errors]

2nd attempt:

```java
import android.content.Context;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LocalFileParser extends ActivityHome {
        Context context;
        String fileName;
        List<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    public LocalFileParser(Context context, String fileName) {
        this.context = context;
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public List<String[]> readCSV() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(fileName);
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        String line;
        String csvSplitBy = ",";

        br.readLine();

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] row = line.split(csvSplitBy);
            rows.add(row);
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

The error for this attempt is the following (in AssetManager.java):

[image: AssetManager import Errors]

Project's dependencies (build.gradle(:app)) :

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:4.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.1'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0@jar'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

Android Studio cannot resolve some imports (for example: `Cannot resolve symbol 'AttrRes'`) and for others it shows the following message `'android.annotation.NonNull' is not public in 'android.annotation'. Cannot be accessed from outside package`.

Thank you :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can browse platform classes such as `AssetManager` or `ContextWrapper` for reference but they cannot be built with the public SDK, and errors like these are normal. For app development you don't need to build them, they are provided by the SDK and the Android platform.

There are some problems with the code you posted - for help with that please specify in detail the problem(s) you need help with.

Comment: Thank you for the response! The specific error is :                                           W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: recipescsv.scv
W/System.err:     at android.content.res.AssetManager.nativeOpenAsset(Native Method)    P.S: The CSV file exists in res folder and it's not empty!

Comment: Really .scv or .csv? Also with AssetManager you open assets, not raw resources.

Comment: Thank you! The problem finally has been fixed with the JSON file and AssetManager.